# jqGrid EditRow ErroFunc Callback Usage

Tags: javascript, java, free-jqgrid

I am using the jqGrid 4.13.3 - free.

I need to use the errofunc callback of the editRow but I get a JavaScript error when accessing the form(page) saying expected ")". In the code I have comments explain what works and then changes made that cause the error.

```
function oSelect(id, status, e) {
  selID = id;
  rejflag = $("#kcdimensionlist").getRowData(id)['rejectedi'];
  $("#kcdimensionlistV7").setColProp('rejectedi', {
    editoptions: {
      dataUrl: '/QMSWebApp/GenericControllerServlet?lifecycle=twowayoptionlist'
    },
    defaultValue: 0
  });
  $("#kcdimensionlistV7").setColProp('rechecki', {
    editoptions: {
      dataUrl: '/QMSWebApp/GenericControllerServlet?lifecycle=threewayoptionlist_NA'
    },
    defaultValue: 0
  });

  var target = $(e.target);

  if (!target.is("img")) {

    if (id && id !== lastsel) {
      $("#kcdimensionlistV7").jqGrid('restoreRow', lastsel);

      //This line works fine but when commented out and modified to next line it fails
      //$("#kcdimensionlistV7").jqGrid('editRow',id,true);
      $("#kcdimensionlistV7").jqGrid('editRow', id, true, errorfunc: eFunc);
      lastsel = id;
    }

  }
};
```

This is my `eFunc` function:

```
function eFunc(response, rowid) {
  var res = $.parseJSON(response.responseText);
  if (res) {
    if (!res.errorCode) {
      return [false, res.errorMsg];
    } else {
      return [true];
    }
  }
}
```

Update to code:

```
function oSelect(id, status, e) {
  selID = id;
  rejflag = $("#kcdimensionlist").getRowData(id)['rejectedi'];
  $("#kcdimensionlistV7").setColProp('rejectedi', {
    editoptions: {
      dataUrl: '/QMSWebApp/GenericControllerServlet?lifecycle=twowayoptionlist'
    },
    defaultValue: 0
  });
  $("#kcdimensionlistV7").setColProp('rechecki', {
    editoptions: {
      dataUrl: '/QMSWebApp/GenericControllerServlet?lifecycle=threewayoptionlist_NA'
    },
    defaultValue: 0
  });

  var target = $(e.target);

  if (!target.is("img")) {

    if (id && id !== lastsel) {

      $("#kcdimensionlistV7").jqGrid('restoreRow', lastsel);

      $("#kcdimensionlistV7").jqGrid('editRow', id, {
        keys: true,
        errorfunc: eFunc
      });
      lastsel = id;
    }

  }
};

function eFunc(response, rowid) {
  alert("Here");
  var res = $.parseJSON(response.responseText);
  if (res) {
    alert(res.errorCode);
    if (!res.errorCode) {
      return [false, res.errorMsg];
    } else {
      return [true];
    }
  }

}
```

This is my servlet code for testing:

```
else if (lifecycle.equals("editdimensiondatamodelV7")) {

  boolean status = false;
  String returnMsg = "This is a test";


  if (request.getParameter("oper").equals("edit")) {



  }


  jReturnString = "{\"errorCode\": " + status + ", \"errorMsg\": \"" + returnMsg + "\"}";
  response.getWriter().write(jReturnString);

}
```

Update:

errorfunc code:

```
function eFunc(res, rowid) {
  var errorText = $.parseJSON(res.responseText).Message;

  alert("Here: " + errorText);
  return [false];
}
```

Servlet code Note comment:

```
else if (lifecycle.equals("editdimensiondatamodelV7")) {
  //Would like to send a dynamic message back - Example: Dimensions are ouside of tolerance     

  if (request.getParameter("oper").equals("edit")) {
    response.setStatus(500);
  }
}
```

The eFunc never returns the alert and a Sending... dialog appears on grid.

Comment: the eFunc is not getting called at all.

Comment: `errorfunc`, like all other callbacks of jqGrid or jQuery, will be called only if the server response have **HTTP error code** (>=400). You can use `response.setStatus(500)` for example (or `response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR`).

Comment: @Oleg: I did get the errorFunc to fire. But this is not what I expected. I want to send edit data to servlet, if it does not meet certain criteria I want to send a message back to caller. Preferably using inline editRow method.

Comment: Typically one just send any data edited by the user to the server. Your server code makes validation and do the changes or return error description understandable by the user. If the server returns successful HTTP code then jqGrid made the changes, if not - it calls `errorfunc` and displays the error message for the user.

Comment: @Oleg: So I get using response.setStatus(500) at the server to fire the errorfunc but how to send the message I create at the server back to errorfunc. I get the errorfunc receives the response but how do I get the message in the response and read it out of the response when the errorfunc fires?

Comment: You should just use correct parameters of `errorfunc`. See [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.15.2/ts/free-jqgrid.d.ts#L1487) that the parameters of `errorfunc` are `rowid, jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown`. Your implementation `eFunc` have wrong order of parameters.

Comment: @Oleg: That was it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fix the line, which contains syntax error

```
$("#kcdimensionlistV7").jqGrid('editRow',id,true, errorfunc: eFunc);
```

to

```
$("#kcdimensionlistV7").jqGrid('editRow', id, {
    keys: true,
    errorfunc: eFunc
});
```

I'd recommend you to upgrade old jqGrid 4.13.3 to the current free jqGrid version: 4.15.2.

Comment: I have now upgraded to the 4.15.2. However, columns in which I have custom icons in for calling various functions are not displaying now as the graphical icon but as literal html code.

Comment: @SteveDyke: your main question is independent from the version of free jqGrid. I can help you with new problem only if you **demonstrate** the problem which you have. Could you provide **the demo**, which shows the problem.

Comment: To solve the initial issue. I have reverted back to 4.13.3

Comment: @SteveDyke: I have one assumption. Probably you render some HTML fragments **on the server side** and include HTML fragments inside of JSON/XML response returned from the server? In the case you should add `autoencode: false` option after updating to version 4.15.2. See README of free jqGrid 4.15.0 for details.

Comment: Yes I am using JSON. This is an example of what I send in the callback as one of the columns data, iconlink = iconlink + "<img title='Dimension Sheet Access' class='modified20 accessdimensionsV7' data-dsindex='" + dsV7.getRecseq() + "' data-faiindex='" + dsV7.getFaiindex() + "' data-partno='" + dsV7.getPartno() + "' src='/QMSWebApp/Images/append[2].jpg'>"; I did try autoencode as false and as true but same result: literal code displays in the column.

Comment: @SteveDyke: One can solve not every problem by guessing. You should use Developer Tools of Chrome/IE (see Network tub) or tools like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to get exact server response returned from the server. Then you can prepare JSFiddle demo, which uses Echo service of JSFiddle with the test data. See https://jsfiddle.net/52boyw5x/2/ as an example. I can help you only if I can reproduce your problem.